# ActionCable doesn't work when changing Redis channel_prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actioncable

I have ActionCable set up with Redis on a Rails server. A JS client is able to connect to the cable URL fine, but will only receive data if the Redis channel prefix is set to `school-safety-server_production` (an old value that it worked for a long time ago). As soon as I change the channel prefix, the JS client is no longer able to receive data from the socket, but it still connects. Is there any reason why Redis would only work for a specific channel prefix? Fresh Redis instances also fail, irregardless of the channel prefix.